# CustomScrollView with SliverPersistentHeader blank in release-apk

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

I implemented a collapsible appbar with A CustomScrollView with a SliverPersistentHeader and SliverList as its slivers. and this works as expected when running the debug apk but when I build a release apk, the page just turns blank. I've failed to figure out why.
[image: release apk blankk page]
[image: Debug apk works fine]

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: CustomSliverAppBarDelegate(
                expandedHeight: 180.h,
              ),
              pinned: true,
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                Padding(
                  padding:
                       EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0, horizontal: 16),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 16.0,
                          bottom: 8.0,
                        ).r,
                        child: Text('Profile',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium),
                      ),
                      ProfileFieldCard(
                          icon: Icons.person,
                          label: 'Name',
                          value: 'Clarissa Hamilton',
                          editValue: () {
                            //do work
                          }),
                     
                       SizedBox(height: 16.r),
                    
                      Card(
                        elevation: 6,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.r),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0).r,
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              InsuranceDetailRow(
                                  label: "holder's name",
                                  value: "Clarissa Hamilton",
                                  icon: Icons.person),           
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you try with `flutter clean` and build again.

Comment: I tried and it hasn't worked

Comment: I got one telling me there was an incorrect use of the Positioned Widget. I just changed the entire implementation and removed the CustomScrollView all together